# Datatables on iOS not scrolling

Tags: jquery, ios, datatables

I'm having a problem with the jQuery plugin DataTables. Everything works just fine in desktop browsers but when I get to the iOS devices the table won't hide the overflow and therefore not scroll either.

I'm populating the table with JavaScript and then calling datatables like:

```
var table = $('#schools-table').DataTable({
    scrollY: $('#schools-table-wrapper').innerHeight() - $('#schools-table-wrapper table thead th').outerHeight(),
    scrollX: '100%',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    ordering: false,
    info: false
});
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table);
```

When I tried it on jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/b56fqsts/1/) I can get it to scroll a little bit. But the fixed left column is still incorrect. So I guess our CSS or something is messed up but I can't seem to locate the error on my own.

If someone can spot the error I would be really grateful.

Regards, Christian

Comment: I wonder if the problem might be that I don't have any text in the cell A1? So when Datatables.FixedColumns calculate th.outerWidth() (despite me specifying the first column to 200px) it returns 11px (which is the padding and border combined.